# Override table styling, Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a site with the Wordpress Twenty Ten theme. I am trying to insert some html tables, but the theme overrides my styling and the tables look awful. I tried to fix this is the CSS file to no avail. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the html: http://pastebin.com/2bX3pD3B
Here is the css: http://pastebin.com/GcWaT0ma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alex: On Ln. 22 of the CSS, remove `table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td` (remove the last `,` on Ln. 21 as well). Then remove Ln. 50 to Ln. 53. This should take care of the CSS rules that are over-riding your own rules.

Comment: Very cool, thank you. The styling is there, but it is still messing up the margins and pushing the secondary widgets down. Any ideas? http://screencast.com/t/e18XhsrR01

Comment: @Alex: Comment out or remove `ol, ul, li,` from Ln. 20 in your CSS, or remove all the negative margins (`margin-left:-35px;`) from the in-line styles on the `<li>` items in your HTML.